# MSBuild project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I Have a question about msbuild integration with Visual Studio 2017 Preview.
I have a custom *.csproj:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Hello World" Importance="High"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I want to add this project to Visual Studio, but i have an error:

> Project file is incomplete. Expected imports are missing

What i need to add to my custom *.csproj to get my project working in Visual Studio?

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: I want to create a project with typescript files and build it as usual c# project.

Comment: If you want to add your custom project to Visual Studio, the simple way is create a new blank project with Visual Studio, then add you custom target into the .csproj file. Besides, Visual Studio supported the typescript, you can download the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-27-vs2017 and create a project with typescript and build it as c# project.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you to create a project from **Visual Studio** or from **dotnet cli**, and then add your custom target to csproj file.

Anyway, I think that the minimal csproj file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This is the template from **dotnet cli**, of course, it depends on your project type (Console, ClassLibrary)